# How to test reduxForm component using enzyme with snapshots?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have presentation component like this

```
 const Login = ({userName}) => {...}

    export default reduxForm({form: "login"})(withStyles(loginStyles)(Login));
```

I need to test Login component by using enzyme lib.
So, if I try to launch this test

```
it("renders correctly_NEW", () => {
        expect(shallow(<Login {...state(false)}/>).dive()).toMatchSnapshot();
      });
```

There is Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(Form(WithStyles(Login)))".

If I launch this test:

```
expect(shallow(<Provider store={configureStore()}><Login {...state(false)}/></Provider>).dive()).toMatchSnapshot();
```

the result is:

```
exports[`LoginForm renders correctly_NEW 1`] = `
<Connect(Form(WithStyles(Login)))
  appName="appName"
  authError={false}
```

But I need snapshot of Login component, not Connect.

p.s. Login component is a presentation - component like this

```
<Form id="form" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
    <Card className={classes.card}>
      <CardHeader
      ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [redux-mock-store](https://github.com/arnaudbenard/redux-mock-store) and put it into the context of the shallow rendered component

```
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store' //ES6 modules
const { configureStore } = require('redux-mock-store') //CommonJS
const middlewares = []
const mockStore = configureStore(middlewares)

it("renders correctly_NEW", () => {

  expect(shallow(
    <Login{...state(false)}/>, 
    {
      context: {store: mockStore}
    }
  ).dive()).toMatchSnapshot();
 });
```

Comment: Store mocking works very good.
But snapshot now contains only top level <Form> on Login, but needs to <Card> and <CardHeader> too if in possible.

Comment: Maybe dive two times or use `mount` instead of `shallow`